# How to make a function dynamic in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm able to create a list with multiple checkboxes and select all option. [Thanks to this answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-fast-m23pu?file=/src/index.js)
Now I have a requirement to make this handleChange function dynamic so that I can reuse this function for multiple state lists. Any help would be appreciated.

```
this.state = {
list1: [
        { name: "item1", isChecked: true },
        { name: "item2", isChecked: true },
        { name: "item3", isChecked: true }
      ]
    };
```

```
<input
          type="checkbox"
          name="checkAll"
          checked={this.state.allChecked}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'list1')}
/>
```

```
handleChange = (e, listName) => {
    let itemName = e.target.name;
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let { list1, allChecked } = prevState;
      if (itemName === "checkAll") {
        allChecked = checked;
        list1 = [listName].map((item) => ({ ...item, isChecked: checked }));
      } else {
        list1 = [listName].map((item) =>
          item.name === itemName ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item
        );
        allChecked = [listName].every((item) => item.isChecked);
      }
      return { list1, allChecked };
    });
  };
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I passed the state list name as an argument to the function and then used it like (allChecked = [listName].every((item) => item.isChecked); I'm unsure how it can be done for this line of code let { list, allChecked } = prevState;

Comment: If I understand it right, `listName` is the list identifier. So, `[listName]` would just hold the name but you want to select the list holding the checkbox items from the state by the name. Can you update the question with the code you've tried?

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about passing the list id to the `handleChange` function. The only thing that is missing is to fetch the list by the id and update its items.

```js
handleChange = (e, listId) => {
  let itemName = e.target.name
  let checked = e.target.checked

  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const { lists } = prevState
    const list = lists[listId]
    if (itemName === 'checkAll') {
      lists[listId] = list.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        isChecked: checked,
      }))
    } else {
      lists[listId] = list.map((item) =>
        item.name === itemName ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item
      )
    }
    return { lists }
  })
}
```

And you don't have to track `allChecked` in the state. It can be computed using `list.every((item) => item.isChecked)`.

The `render` method becomes

```js
const { lists } = this.state
return (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(this.state.lists).map((listId) => {
      const list = lists[listId]
      const allChecked = list.every((item) => item.isChecked)
      return (
        <div className="list" key={listId}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="checkAll"
            checked={allChecked}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, listId)}
          />
          Check all
          <br />
          {list.map((item) => (
            <div key={`${listId}-${item.name}`}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={item.name}
                value={item.name}
                checked={item.isChecked}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, listId)}
              />
              <label>{item.name}</label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lists-69mtv)